# ArrayList. Как получить эффект аналогичный: String[] a = "abc".split("");

Tags: java, строки, коллекции

У строки есть метод `split("regExp")` а есть возможность рассплитить сразу в `ArrayList`? Или может есть какая-то еще коллекция которая это поддерживает? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: `List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc".split(""));` получен список фиксированного размера. `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("abc".split("")));` получен ArrayList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `split(String regex)` возвращает массив строк, то есть `String[]`.

В классе `String` нету подобного по функционалу метода, который бы возвращал не массив, а какую-либо коллекцию.

Как вариант, полученный массив можно преобразовать в `ArrayList<String>`, например, так:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("abc".split("")));
```